# Live updating ASP.NET webpage from Azure SQL database

Tags: asp.net, signalr, openlayers, azure-sql-database

I am creating a ASP.NET website that pulls data from an Azure SQL database and plots it on a map using OpenLayers.  I'm ok with pulling the data initially and plotting it, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about making it update live. I've seen some ideas but I'm not really sure what is possible/best practice.

1. At high traffic times, the database will be being updated my several users every minute or so.  What is the best way to get the new/updated records to the webpage to update the map live/semi-live?
2. I've seen lots of stuff about SignalR and it sounds a lot better than a periodic polling approach, but I'm a little lost on how to implement it.  The way I understand it I need to have a hub to send out updates to the website, but is this hub within the ASP.NET application or is it it's own thing that I would need to create?  There is a Mobile Service for entering the data into the database, could the hub be implemented in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You already answered this question. SignalR is a perfect fit for this.
2. There's [plenty of resources](http://www.asp.net/signalr) out there that can tell you how to setup and use SignalR in your web application. As to where it can be hosted, you have several options, but the most common approach is to host it within the ASP.NET application, both for simplicity, and because for SignalR to support web socket transport, it needs to be hosted on IIS.